# How to customize the TotalRecordCount and Paging after filter in jTable jquery (Java-JSP)

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, jquery-jtable

I use a jTable jquery for jsp page, it work very well. It can display the  showing count records in bottom right of table well (e.g. Showing 1-10 of 22). When I insert the Filtering into the page, the showing count record is not correctly.

I follow this for Filtering: http://www.jtable.org/Demo/Filtering

How to customize the code for showing count record (I use java-jsp and sql server). Sorry for my English language :))

Here is the code I am using right now in controller.

```
if (action.equals("list")) {           
    try {    
        int startPageIndex      = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("jtStartIndex"));
        int numRecordsPerPage   = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("jtPageSize"));
        String jtSorting = null;
        //Fetch Data from Rejected_Product Table                    
        lstSite = dao.**getAllSite**(filter_site, startPageIndex, numRecordsPerPage, jtSorting);

        //Get Total Record Count for Pagination
        int siteCount = dao.**getSiteCount**();

        //Convert Java Object to Json
        Gson gson = new Gson();     
        JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(lstSite, new TypeToken<List<Site>>() {
        }.getType());
        JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
        String listData = jsonArray.toString();

        //Return Json in the format required by jTable plugin
        listData = "{\"Result\":\"OK\",\"Records\":"+listData+",\"TotalRecordCount\":"+siteCount+"}";
        response.getWriter().print(listData);
        System.out.println(listData);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        String error = "{\"Result\":\"ERROR\",\"Message\":" + ex.getStackTrace() + "}";
        response.getWriter().print(error);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and here method getAllSite:

```
public List<Site> getAllSite (FilterSite filter_site, int jtStartIndex, int jtPageSize, String jtSorting) {
        List<Site> siteList = new ArrayList<Site>();                
        String query = "";

        String siteQ        = filter_site.getSite();
        String clientQ      = filter_site.getClient(); // wait
        String locationQ    = filter_site.getLocation();
            if (locationQ.isEmpty()) {
                locationQ = "";
            } else {
                locationQ = "and location like '%"+locationQ+"' ";
            }
        String site_idQ     = filter_site.getSite_id();
            if (site_idQ.isEmpty()) {
                site_idQ = "";
            } else {
                site_idQ = "and site_id = '"+site_idQ+"' ";
            }                       
        String divisionQ    = filter_site.getDivision();
            if (divisionQ.isEmpty()) {
                divisionQ = "";
            } else {
                divisionQ = "and division = '"+divisionQ+"' ";
            }

        int range   = jtStartIndex+jtPageSize;

        query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CODE) as row FROM [site]) a "
                    + "WHERE (code like '%"+siteQ+"' "+locationQ+site_idQ+divisionQ+") "
                    + "and row > "+jtStartIndex+" and row <= "+range;

        try {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("query : "+query);

            while (rs.next()) {
                Site sitebean = new Site();
                sitebean.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                sitebean.setCode(rs.getString("code"));
                .....

                siteList.add(sitebean);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return siteList;
}
```

and here method getSiteCount :

```
public int getSiteCount () {
    int count = 0;
    String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM [site] ";
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs        = statement.executeQuery(query); 
            while (rs.next()) { 
                count = rs.getInt("count");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by "not correctly" that the row count is larger than expected, then the solution would be to include the where clause in the siteCount query.

WHERE (code like '%"+siteQ+"' "+locationQ+site_idQ+divisionQ+")